# How to get non-group by column X value of the first row of every group by column Y of table T?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table T with columns X, Y and Z. I need to retrieve non-group by column X value of the first row of every group, group by column Y value, and MIN of column Z value in a SQL single query.

Please could you help me out.

Comment: That's hard to parse.  Maybe you could show sample output?

Comment: Specifically, what do you mean by 'first'.

Comment: If I'm not parsing this wrongly, does he try to say that he's has a query like SELECT Y, MIN(Z) FROM T GROUP BY Y and now whether is it possible to also retrieve the X value of the very first row within group Y (assuming they were already sorted by some sort of ID) in the same query?

Comment: Yes Seh, you were parsing it correctly. I could have describe my question properly. Any way, I got my answer from lins314159.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've assumed that you've got a column x_dt that can be used to determine the first row of a Y group.

```
SELECT
  x,
  y,
  z
FROM (SELECT
  x,
  y,
  MIN(z) OVER (PARTITION BY y) AS z,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY y ORDER BY x_dt) AS rn
FROM T) T2
WHERE rn = 1;
```